# Consolidating a List of Dates with 2 columns being equal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a List of  that comes from a sql table, This is what the model looks like below:

```
public class ReservationReport
    {
        public string HotelName { get; set; }
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public DateTime Arrive { get; set; }
        public DateTime AMDepart { get; set; }
        public int companypay { get; set; }
        public int selfpay { get; set; }
        public int guestID { get; set; }
        public string RoomType { get; set; }
        public int Inventory_ID { get; set; }
        public int HotelID { get; set; }
    }
```

The list is currently all separated by each day.  I need to combine it in a way that shows Hotel and which members stayed by how many days for example:

List coming in from sql will look like this

- -Hotel 1 John smith,   Feb 1 - Feb 2
- -Hotel 1 John smith,   Feb 2 - Feb 3
- -Hotel 1 Someone Else, Feb 1 - Feb2
- -Hotel 1 John smith ,  Feb 10- Feb 11

List should show something like this:

- Hotel 1 John smith,   Feb 1- Feb3 (Stayed 2 days)
- Hotel 1 Someone else, Feb 1- Feb2 (stayed 1 day)
- Hotel 1 John Smith,   Feb10- Feb11 (Stayed 1 day)

What I have currently is the following code.  The problem I have is when a person has stayed in the same hotel but on days outside of touching they are only put once in the combined list.  This is what I have currently

```
CombinedList = temp2.GroupBy(m => new { m.guestID, m.HotelID }).Select(group => group.First()).ToList();
                foreach (var item in CombinedList)
                {
                    // disposable list to get values for only the correct records 
                    List<ReservationReport> dispose = temp2.Where(x => x.HotelID == item.HotelID && x.guestID  == item.guestID ).ToList();
                    item.Arrive = dispose.Min(i => i.Arrive);
                    item.AMDepart = dispose.Max(i => i.AMDepart);
                    item.selfpay = dispose.Sum(i => i.selfpay);
                    item.companypay = dispose.Sum(i => i.companypay);
                }
```

After I run the above code my Combined List looks like the below

- Hotel 1 Someone else, Feb 1- Feb2 (stayed 1 day)
- Hotel 1 John Smith,   Feb1- Feb11 (Stayed 10 day)

My combinedList call is only giving me 2 rows when it should contain 3, the problem is I am not sure how to lambda or linq with the 2 variables and where the dates are next to each other in this manner.

any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm still searching for the post where I learned about this approach; will refer to it in this post when I find it.)

You could use [`.Aggregate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0) with a special accumulator to achieve your desired results.

```csharp
List<ReservationReport> summary = temp2
    .OrderBy(r => r.Arrive)
    .GroupBy(r => ( r.guestID, r.HotelID ))
    .Select(gr => gr.Skip(1).Aggregate(
        ( Visits: new List<ReservationReport>(), LatestStay: new ReservationReport(gr.First()) ),
        ( guestReport, reservation ) => {
            if (reservation.Arrive.Date == guestReport.LatestStay.AMDepart.Date) 
            {
                guestReport.LatestStay.ExtendWith(reservation);
            }
            else
            {
                guestReport.Visits.Add(guestReport.LatestStay);
                guestReport.LatestStay = new ReservationReport(reservation);
            }
            
            return guestReport;
        },
        guestReport => guestReport.Visits.Concat(new[] { guestReport.LatestStay })))
    .SelectMany(visit => visit)
    .ToList();
```

1. First, the reservation reports are ordered chronologically by `Arrival`. This is necessary to make sure `.Aggregate()` will work.
2. Then, the reservation reports are grouped (as OP has suggested) by `guestID` and `HotelID`
3. Now, `.Aggregate()` is used to combine reservations that are connected to each other for **guest X at hotel Y**:

   - the special accumulator is a named tuple `( Visits, LatestStay )` which is referred to in the code as `guestReport`
   - `Visits` is a list containing the accumulated visits / consecutive stays of **guest X at hotel Y**. Initially, this is empty.
   - for each reservation made by **guest X at hotel Y**, its `Arrive` value is compared to the current accumulated stay (`LatestStay`)'s `AMDepart` value; if they match, `LatestStay` is prolonged.
   - at the end, `.Aggregate()` returns all the separate visits made by **guest X at hotel Y** (by returning `Visits` concatenated with `LatestStay`).

---

The `ReservationReport` class is extended as follows for this purpose:

```
public class ReservationReport
{
    public ReservationReport() { }

    public ReservationReport(ReservationReport existing)
    {
        HotelName = existing.HotelName;
        // Copying all property values...
        HotelID = existing.HotelID;
    }

    // Properties
    
    public void ExtendWith(ReservationReport other)
    {
        AMDepart = other.AMDepart;
        selfpay += other.selfpay;
        companypay += other.companypay;
    }
}
```

---

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wpdylp).

Comment: Thank you, not only this solved it but I also learned with your explanation.  Very much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it is both helpful and educational!

Answer (score 1):

I modified the codes you've shown in your controller,and it seems work well:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var reservationreport1 = new ReservationReport()
            {
                Report_ID = 1,
                guestID = 1,
                Name = "a1",
                HotelID = 1,
                HotelName = "h1",
                Arrive = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1),
                AMDepart = new DateTime(2021, 1, 2)
            };
            var reservationreport2 = new ReservationReport()
            {
                Report_ID = 2,
                guestID = 1,
                Name = "a1",
                HotelID = 1,
                HotelName = "h1",
                Arrive = new DateTime(2021, 1, 2),
                AMDepart = new DateTime(2021, 1, 3)
            };
            var reservationreport3 = new ReservationReport()
            {
                Report_ID = 3,
                guestID = 1,
                Name = "a1",
                HotelID = 1,
                HotelName = "h1",
                Arrive = new DateTime(2021, 1, 3),
                AMDepart = new DateTime(2021, 1, 4)
            };

            var reservationreport4 = new ReservationReport()
            {
                Report_ID = 4,
                guestID = 2,
                Name = "a2",
                HotelID = 1,
                HotelName = "h1",
                Arrive = new DateTime(2021, 1, 4),
                AMDepart = new DateTime(2021, 1, 5)
            };
            var reservationreport5 = new ReservationReport()
            {
                Report_ID = 5,
                guestID = 1,
                Name = "a1",
                HotelID = 1,
                HotelName = "h1",
                Arrive = new DateTime(2021, 1, 6),
                AMDepart = new DateTime(2021, 1, 7)
            };
            var reportlist = new List<ReservationReport>() { };
            reportlist.Add(reservationreport1);
            reportlist.Add(reservationreport2);
            reportlist.Add(reservationreport3);
            reportlist.Add(reservationreport4);
            reportlist.Add(reservationreport5);
            var templist = new List<ReservationReport>();
            reportlist.ForEach(m => { templist.Add(m); });
            foreach (var item in reportlist)
            {
                Ressetlist(templist, item);
            }
            var targetlist = templist.OrderBy(m => m.guestID).ThenBy(m => m.HotelID).ThenBy(m => m.Report_ID).ToList();
            return View();
        }




public List<ReservationReport> Ressetlist(List<ReservationReport> reservationreports, ReservationReport item)
        {
            List<ReservationReport> dispose = reservationreports.Where(x => x.HotelID == item.HotelID && x.guestID == item.guestID).ToList();
            var tempitem = dispose.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Arrive == item.AMDepart);
            if(tempitem!=null)
            {
                reservationreports.Remove(item);
                reservationreports.Remove(tempitem);
                item.AMDepart = tempitem.AMDepart;
                reservationreports.Add(item);
                Ressetlist( reservationreports,item);
            }
            return reservationreports;
        }
```

Result：
[image: Result1]
[image: Result2]
[image: Result3]

Comment: Thanks for the help Ruikai, I will be using Astrid solution, But this will work also for my needs.  Thank you for helping me.